# Mocking Firebase Messages in a Functional Espresso Test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-espresso

How can I mock receiving a message from FCM in my functional Espresso Test on Android?

I have tried to send an Intent to [Context.startService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startService(android.content.Intent)) with an action of `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` to start my FirebaseMessagingService but `onMessageReceived` is never called.

Do I just need to extract the logic in the service to a different class and test it and ignore Firebase Messaging, or I could convert my functional test into an integration test and actually send a message to Firebase?

`#AskFirebase`